# How to echo excerpts with wp_list_pages?

Tags: pages, query, excerpt, wp-list-pages

I've tried to echo excerpts in `wp_list_pages` with the code below. It works, but only for one of the child pages. How would I echo the excerpt and title for each child page?

```
<?php
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
if ($children) { ?>
    <h2>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
    </h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make use of all the nifty filters for the title and excerpt/content (and why would you not want that?) you should loop through a custom query instead of using `get_pages` and the pages' plain contents:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php
    the_excerpt();
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this one is preventing the page from loading.

Comment: I wonder why this code only lists one page. :-/

Comment: The code above only lists one of the first-level/direct children - I would like it to list all first-level/direct children. (But not further descendants.)

Comment: The output is NULL

Comment: Unfortunately, this is true. Take a look (with debugging removed) I marked this as "Your code without debugging:"
http://themeforward.com/demo2/?page_id=2535

Comment: Huge output: http://themeforward.com/demo2/?page_id=2535

Comment: There is now, without the var_dump there wasn't. Here's the full page code: http://snippi.com/s/yhwe8nv

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see why this is not working as expected. This is just a wild guess, but please try to rename `$pages` to `$query`, then test again. You have to rename all three occurrences of `$page` of course. ;) And you can delete the `var_dump`.

Comment: Workedwith $query!

Comment: That is really strange! But I'm glad it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

`wp_list_pages()` is for displaying a list of pages. It looks like you want to do more with it.

Instead you should use `get_pages()` with returns an array of data about the pages which means you have much more flexibility with it. Here's some sample code:

```
$children = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID));

foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
   <h2><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></h2>
   <p><?php echo $child->post_excerpt; ?></p>
   <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($child->ID); ?>"><?php echo $child->post_title; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Feel free to add a better solution - no good just saying you think there's a better solution if you can't provide any code.

Comment: Any idea what the best way to make the post_title a link would be?

Comment: I've added an example LI with a link in the example.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to limit this to immediate children pages of the parent? (Thanks for the update, by the way.)

Comment: Use parent instead of child_of

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this the way you are attempting. All of the markup is generated by `wp_list_pages()`. You can't "insert" content like that.

You can apply a callback to the [`wp_list_pages`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L864) hook but you'd need some tricky regex to do it.

I think your best option is to pass a custom Walker to `wp_list_pages()`. Something like this:

```
class My_Page_Walker extends Walker_Page {
  function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= apply_filters('the_excerpt',$page->post_excerpt);  
    // or generate the excerpt from post_content
    // $output .= apply_filters('the_content',wp_trim_words($page->post_content));
    $output .= '</li>';
  }
}

$args = array(
  'post_status'=> 'publish',
  'walker' => new My_Page_Walker
);

wp_list_pages( $args );
```